# Send flash video stream to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, webcam.js

I want to make a script that will help user to center his face in the capture preview. Some `<div>` that would keep his outline green if the face is kept in a defined area and red if the face goes out.

For capture, I use [Webcam.js](https://pixlcore.com/read/WebcamJS) a library with Flash fail-back.
For tracking, I'm using [Tracking.JS](https://trackingjs.com/) that can handle object detection from a video element.

The goal is to make a real time face positioning plugin.

**Different preview modes of Webcam.js :**

- The HTML5 preview :

*A video element created by WEBCAM.JS that has for src attribute the video stream of `getUserMedia` function. (The video is nice handled by TRACKING.JS)*

- The Flash preview (IE Fail-back):

*A `.swf` object (webcam.swf) whos prompts access of camera, displays the preview -IN THE FLASH MOTOR- and when the user snaps, it send back the picture to Javascript.*

**HERE IS MY PROBLEM:**

Is there a way to build/edit swf file to make it send the video stream to javascript ? (Instead of only the picture when the snap is fired) The goal is to TRACKING.JS as well the HTML5 stream than the flash one in case of.

Webcam.swf > [Here is Github directory of Actionscript files.](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/tree/master/flash)

Thank  you.